# Keeping text upper and lower case in MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, case-sensitive

**I understand the title can be confusing, was having trouble wording it. If Someone can come up with a better phrasing, feel free to change it.**

When I pass in values to the database in MySQL, the 'case' of the text is passed in all well and good, as well as when I retrieve it, So for example:

*Stored in the Db, and when retrieved:*

```
Username: Ben
Password: PassWord
```

But when I query it, I can search for

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Username = 'ben' AND Password = 'password';
```

And there is no restriction on font case. Is there a way to set it so that if the above query is used, it will return nothing, but if I use

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Username = 'Ben' and Password = 'PassWord';
```

ONLY this will return the data?

Comment: You will want to look at collation. Therein lies your solution.

I don't know what you're using in C# to read from MySQL. I can probably give a code snippet if I knew which library/framework you are using to connect to MySQL. In LINQ (such as in EntityFramework), you can assert that two strings are case sensitive like this: myObject = someQueryable.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Equals("someString", StringComparison.Ordinal)

Also, please don't tell me you're storing passwords in an unencrypted format. :)

Comment: not to worry, all private credentials are safely encrypted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "Case sensitivity". This can be accomplished in MySQL using collation or in C# using the `StringInstance.Equals` method with it's optional `StringComparison` parameter. Usually programming languages are case-sensitive in string comparisons and database query languages are case insensitive (more properly, default collation is case-insensitive) so this can be quite confusing.

If you want to do this in the SQL Query itself, you'll want to [collate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) the string in your query.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Password = 'PassWord' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

See related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737805/mysql-case-sensitive-in-utf8-general-ci) (in PHP, but still using MySQL)

If you are generating the query from, say, EntityFramework, you will want to want to use an somestring.Equals(someOtherString) method with [StringComparsion.Ordinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Example:

```
MyObject obj = someQueryable.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Password.Equals("PassWord", StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

This will cause the generated query to contain the proper collation code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare String `case sensitive` then use Collation  `latin1_bin`. Default Collation is `latin1_swedish_ci` which is case insensitive.

```
SELECT * FROM 
       TableName 
              WHERE Username COLLATE latin1_bin = 'Ben' 
               AND Password COLLATE latin1_bin = 'PassWord';
```

Try this

Comment: It says invalid collation 'latin1_bin'? May i know how to find the list of collation made available?

Comment: In phpmyadmin click on structure and check list of collation to edit particular field or column

Answer (score -3):

Sorry to mix it up:

First it's a very very bad idea to store your passwords in plain-text, because if your server get's compromised, all you user-passwords can be used to hijack user's accounts elsewhere.

You can use a hash (yeah i know, it's compromised too, but a bit more secure):

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE Username = 'Ben' AND Password = SHA1('PassWord')
```

Then you have to insert it, for sure, as `sha1`-hash!

The Problem with that is, that the password will EVER STAY case-sensitive, at least if you won't lower/uppercase it BEFORE insertation.

```
INSERT INTO table (Username, Password) VALUES ('Ben', SHA1(LOWER('PassWord'));
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Username = 'Ben' AND Password =  SHA1(LOWER('PassWord'));
```

Will work, but it reduces hash entropy, since the character-set is limited to lower-case alpha.
You should avoid that too.

Clear: Use Hasing for password and leave it CASE SENSITIVE.

For Username Case-sensivity try:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(Username) = LOWER('BeN');
```